# how to change the field value from another class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created MyApp class and I created method(setHeight) in it

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

void setHeight(){
      CustomLayout().height = 0;
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have created another class named CustomLayout.

```
class CustomLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  double height;
  double width;
  CustomLayout({this.height = 40, this.width = 40});
  @override
  _CustomLayoutState createState() => _CustomLayoutState();
}

class _CustomLayoutState extends State<CustomLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      color : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I called this setHeight method in main.dart in floatingactionbutton

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {MyApp().setHeight()},
            ),
```

But value of height doesnt change and it still have the height 40.
Please help me to change the height of the CustomLayout class from setHeight method in MyApp class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to set height, you call widget and pass parameter inside it

like:

```
Container(
      child: CustomLayout(height:0) // this is the explict height, constructor height is default
      ),
```